# JavaScript triggered by click on CSS class, but I need it triggered from an HTML map area hotspot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, only did a few copy/paste implementations of readily available code. But that doesn't help me here. :-(

So I found a pretty neat jQuery "page Transition" tutorial, setting the body display css tag to "None" on start and then do a neat Little fade in.

There also is a fade out function but the thing is in this tutorial it will only be triggered if a  link with a specific class is clicked.

BUT: I need this fade out to happen after an HTML map hotspot is clicked - and those cannot have a css class applied to them I reckon.

There must be a way to call the fade out function from this HTML map area hotspot, yes? And if so, will that function still be able to grab the destination URL?

This would be the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(500);

    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);       
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
</script>
```

So THIS works like a charm:

```
<a href="page2.html" class="transition">Click to fade to Page 2</a>
```

But that do I do with THIS?:

```
<img src="graphics/menu_01.jpg" alt="" usemap="#maincontent" id="maincontent"/>
<map name="maincontent">
  <area shape="rect" coords="438,264,578,411" href="page2.html">
</map>
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: try `$("map>area").hover(function(){event.preventDefault();linkLocation = this.href;$("body").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);});`? that should make it fade to Page 2 whenever you hover over that hotspot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `transition` class to your `area` element.
2. Change your selector to this one: `$(".transition")`.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7sq6tpc1/1/)

Comment: Wohooo! :) That was even easier as I already expected! Really need to dig in deeper into JavaScript.

THX, also to Huey, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @todddeece Your welcome, you can accept it as correct answer if it helped. Also post your another question in a new topic (not as an answer here).